# Drag and Drop ( Drag um item já dropado )

Tags: javascript, html5, drag-n-drop

Bom dia!! 
Estou precisando de uma ajuda em JScript.
Fiz um código de Drag and Drop onde coloco um gif dentro da div conteudo e posso move-lo livremente. Só não estou conseguindo fazer o seguinte: 
Ao tentar dropar um gif próximo a um item já dropado na div conteudo, o gif empurrar o item dropado.(Atualmente, o item some quando tento colocar na imagem já dropada).
Podem me ajudar?? :( 
Segue o código como exemplo:

```js
  var elementCounter = 0; // to assign ids to dropped element.
  //Drag'n Drop functions
  function allowDrop(ev) 
  {
      ev.preventDefault();
  }

  function drag(ev) 
  {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
        ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "copy"; 
  }

  function drop(ev) 
  {
      ev.preventDefault();
      var x = ev.clientX;
      var y = ev.clientY;
      var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
      var copyimg = document.createElement("img");
      var original = document.getElementById(data);
      copyimg.src = original.src;
      ev.target.appendChild(copyimg);
      if(original.parentNode.id == "conteudo")
     { 
        original.parentNode.removeChild(original);
        alert("Movendo imagem");
        copyimg.id = "dropped_elem"+(++elementCounter);
        copyimg.setAttribute("style", "position: fixed; top: "+(y-50)+"px; left:"+(x-50)+"px;");
        copyimg.setAttribute('draggable', true);
        copyimg.setAttribute('ondragstart', "drag(event)");
      } else {
        alert("Nova imagem");
        copyimg.id = "dropped_elem"+(++elementCounter);
        copyimg.setAttribute("style", "position: fixed; top: "+(y-50)+"px; left:"+(x-50)+"px;");
        copyimg.setAttribute('draggable', true);
        copyimg.setAttribute('ondragstart', "drag(event)");
      }
  }
```

```css
    #conteudo{
      width:500px;
      height:500px;
      float:left;
      background-color:#ff1;  
      display: initial;
      margin: auto;
      z-index: 6;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
```

```html
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
  <body>
    <img id="drag1" width="70" src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/0772/f/2015/291/2/9/29820d36256689bdeae12f344e4f0b7a-d9djrwh.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"  alt="" />
    <img id="drag1" width="70" src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/0772/f/2015/291/2/9/29820d36256689bdeae12f344e4f0b7a-d9djrwh.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"  alt="" />
    <img id="drag1" width="70" src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/0772/f/2015/291/2/9/29820d36256689bdeae12f344e4f0b7a-d9djrwh.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"  alt="" />
    <div id="conteudo" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Isso que você quer é mais matemático do que pelo código, com o seu código mesmo da pra fazer isso, você precisa captar a posição e o tamanho dos dois elementos, e comparar dentro do pai se eles se encontram em algum momento, acho que a equação das retas básica você consegue cruzar um ou e o outro, caso cruze, só disparar mudando a posição com a proporção da sobreposição, se não conseguir ou ninguém mais responder a noite faço uma resposta, pois vai ser meio longa.

Comment: Entendi !
O disparar será feito pelo .setAttribute("style", "position: fixed; ... certo??
Porém ainda não tenho ideia de como compara-los, vou tentar algo aqui !! Obg :DD

Comment: Isso mesmo, você capta com o mesmo seletor também, só imaginar a div que os elementos estão dentro como um plano cartesiano(X,Y) pra conseguir aplicar a equação, desenha numa folha que vais entender facinho.

Comment: Beleza !! obg !!

Comment: Não consegui, após inserir a imagem dentro de outra imagem, ele não respeita o comando para mover para o lado, a imagem simplesmente some

Comment: coloca o codigo que você fez na pergunta, não tenho tempo pra fazer uma resposta completa, mas vo ajudando

Comment: Eu coloquei um else para diferenciar se é uma nova imagem ou se está movendo uma imagem da div conteúdo.
A única coisa que não consigo é diferenciar se esta nova imagem está caindo na div conteúdo ou em cima de outra imagem...
Pois se eu soltar uma imagem (²) em cima de uma outra imagem (¹), a imagem (²) some

Comment: É meio complicado, vou mover para o chat e tentar explicar um pouco melhor

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65827/discussion-between-anthraxisbr-and-sora).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver esta questão substituindo o `ev.target.appendChild(copyimg);` por `div.appendChild(copyimg);` antes do if.